# Replacing a Mocked Spring Boot Controller with the actual Controller

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm new to Spring Boot and Testing.

tl;dr How do I replace a @MockBean controller with the actual controller, in a spring boot application so that I can test that the controller is working instead of just testing that my objects are output correctly?

I'm writing a gradle managed API with dependencies (from build.gradle):

```
// Spring Boot (2.0.5 Release)
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

// Testing
testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1')
testRuntimeOnly('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1')
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
testCompile("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.11.1")
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.+'
```

I've got an API controller class with the following relevant code:

```
@Controller
public class ObjectivesApiController extends AbstractRestHelperFunctionality implements ObjectivesApi {

protected ObjectivesApiController(
        UserRepository userRepository,
        CompaniesRepository companiesRepository,
        TeamsRepository teamsRepository,
        ProjectsRepository projectsRepository,
        OdiAssessmentRepository odiAssessmentRepository,
        OdiCustomerRatingRepository odiCustomerRatingRepository,
        OdiTechRatingRepository odiTechRatingRepository,
        OdiValueRatingRepository odiValueRatingRepository,
        ObjectivesRepository objectivesRepository,
        KeyResultRepository keyResultRepository) {
    super(
            userRepository,
            companiesRepository,
            teamsRepository,
            projectsRepository,
            odiAssessmentRepository,
            odiCustomerRatingRepository,
            odiTechRatingRepository,
            odiValueRatingRepository,
            objectivesRepository,
            keyResultRepository);
}

public ResponseEntity<KeyResult> createKeyResult(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id, @ApiParam(value = "keyResult", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody KeyResult keyResultDTO) {

    KeyResult keyResult = KeyResultBuilder
            .aKeyResult()
            .withDescription(keyResultDTO.getDescription())
            .withCompleted(keyResultDTO.getCompleted())
            .build();

    Objective parentObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id);
    parentObjective.addKeyResult(keyResult);
    keyResultRepository.save(keyResult);
    objectivesRepository.save(parentObjective);

    return new ResponseEntity<KeyResult>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

public ResponseEntity<Objective> createObjective(@ApiParam(value = "objective", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Objective objectiveDTO) {

    Objective objective = ObjectiveBuilder
            .anObjective()
            .withDescription(objectiveDTO.getDescription())
            .withCompleted(objectiveDTO.getCompleted())
            .withKeyResults(objectiveDTO.getKeyResults())
            .build();

    objective.getKeyResults().forEach(keyResultRepository::save);

    objectivesRepository.save(objective);
    return new ResponseEntity<Objective>(HttpStatus.CREATED);
}

public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteAllLinkedKeyResults(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id);

    subjectObjective.getKeyResults().clear();
    objectivesRepository.save(subjectObjective);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteObjective(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    objectivesRepository.delete(objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id));
    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteOneKeyResult(@ApiParam(value = "the id of the objective you want key results for", required = true) @PathVariable("objectiveId") Long objectiveId, @ApiParam(value = "the id of the key result", required = true) @PathVariable("keyResultId") Long keyResultId) {
    Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(objectiveId);
    KeyResult keyResult = keyResultRepository.findByKeyResultId(keyResultId);

    subjectObjective.removeKeyResult(keyResult);

    objectivesRepository.save(subjectObjective);
    keyResultRepository.delete(keyResult);

    return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

public ResponseEntity<List<Objective>> getAllObjectives() {
    List<Objective> allObjectives = objectivesRepository.findAll();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Objective>>(allObjectives, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<List<KeyResult>> getKeyResultsForObjective(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id);
    List<KeyResult> allKeyResults = subjectObjective.getKeyResults();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<KeyResult>>(allKeyResults, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<Objective> getObjective(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id);
    return new ResponseEntity<Objective>(subjectObjective, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<KeyResult> getKeyResultForObjective(@ApiParam(value = "the id of the objective you want key results for", required = true) @PathVariable("objectiveId") Long objectiveId, @ApiParam(value = "the id of the key result", required = true) @PathVariable("keyResultId") Long keyResultId) {
    Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(objectiveId);
    KeyResult subjecKeyResult = subjectObjective.getKeyResults().stream()
            .filter(KeyResult -> keyResultId.equals(KeyResult.getKeyResultId()))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null);

    return new ResponseEntity<KeyResult>(subjecKeyResult, HttpStatus.OK);
}

public ResponseEntity<Objective> updateObjective(@ApiParam(value = "id", required = true) @PathVariable("id") Long id, @ApiParam(value = "objective", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody Objective objectiveDTO) {

    Objective existingObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(id);

    Objective objective = ObjectiveBuilder
            .anObjective()
            .withObjectiveId(existingObjective.getObjectiveId())
            .withDescription(objectiveDTO.getDescription())
            .withCompleted(objectiveDTO.getCompleted())
            .withKeyResults(objectiveDTO.getKeyResults())
            .build();

    objective.getKeyResults().forEach(keyResultRepository::save);

    objectivesRepository.save(objective);
    return new ResponseEntity<Objective>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

public ResponseEntity<KeyResult> updateKeyResult(@ApiParam(value = "the id of the objective you want key results for", required = true) @PathVariable("objectiveId") Long objectiveId, @ApiParam(value = "the id of the key result", required = true) @PathVariable("keyResultId") Long keyResultId, @ApiParam(value = "keyResult", required = true) @Valid @RequestBody KeyResult keyResultDTO) {
    if (objectivesRepository.existsById(objectiveId) && keyResultRepository.existsById(keyResultId)) {
        Objective subjectObjective = objectivesRepository.findByObjectiveId(objectiveId);

        KeyResult subjecKeyResult = subjectObjective.getKeyResults().stream()
                .filter(KeyResult -> keyResultId.equals(KeyResult.getKeyResultId()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        KeyResult updatedKeyResult = KeyResultBuilder
                .aKeyResult()
                .withKeyResultId(subjecKeyResult.getKeyResultId())
                .withDescription(keyResultDTO.getDescription())
                .withCompleted(keyResultDTO.getCompleted())
                .build();

        keyResultRepository.save(updatedKeyResult);

        Collections.replaceAll(subjectObjective.getKeyResults(), subjecKeyResult, updatedKeyResult);

        objectivesRepository.save(subjectObjective);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity<KeyResult>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
}

}
```

For context on this class, all the AbstractRestHelper super class is doing, is creating singletons of my repositories, which are then .. field injected (unsure if this is the right term) in to the controller. This pattern is repeated across all controllers hence the clutter.

The API being implemented is a Swagger 2 API interface that keeps this controller free of annotations where possible.

The final piece is the test class. This is the core of my question.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(ObjectivesApiController.class)
class ObjectivesApiControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ObjectivesApiController objectivesApiControllerMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
    }

    @Test
    void getAllObjectives() throws Exception {
        // Create two objects to test with:

        Objective testObjective1 = ObjectiveBuilder
                .anObjective()
                .withObjectiveId(1L)
                .withDescription("Test Objective")
                .withCompleted(false)
                .build();

        Objective testObjective2 = ObjectiveBuilder
                .anObjective()
                .withObjectiveId(2L)
                .withDescription("Test Objective")
                .withCompleted(true)
                .build();

        List<Objective> testList = new ArrayList<Objective>();
        testList.add(testObjective1);
        testList.add(testObjective2);

        // Set expectations on what should be found:
        when(objectivesApiControllerMock.getAllObjectives()).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<List<Objective>>(testList, HttpStatus.OK));

        // Carry out the mocked API call:
        mockMvc.perform(get("/objectives"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].objectiveId", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].description", is("Test Objective")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].completed", is(false)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].objectiveId", is(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].description", is("Test Objective")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].completed", is(true)));


        // Validate the response is what we expect:
        verify(objectivesApiControllerMock, times(1)).getAllObjectives();
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(objectivesApiControllerMock);

    }

    @Test
    void getKeyResultsForObjective() throws Exception {

        KeyResult testKeyResultWithParentObjective1 = KeyResultBuilder
                .aKeyResult()
                .withKeyResultId(1L)
                .withCompleted(false)
                .withDescription("My parent Key Result is 1")
                .build();

        KeyResult testKeyResultWithParentObjective2 = KeyResultBuilder
                .aKeyResult()
                .withKeyResultId(2L)
                .withCompleted(true)
                .withDescription("My parent Key Result is 1")
                .build();

        Objective testObjectiveWithKeyResults = ObjectiveBuilder
                .anObjective()
                .withObjectiveId(1L)
                .withDescription("Test Objective")
                .withKeyResults(new ArrayList<KeyResult>())
                .withCompleted(false)
                .build();

        testObjectiveWithKeyResults.addKeyResult(testKeyResultWithParentObjective1);
        testObjectiveWithKeyResults.addKeyResult(testKeyResultWithParentObjective2);

        when(objectivesApiControllerMock.getKeyResultsForObjective(1L)).thenReturn(new ResponseEntity<List<KeyResult>>(testObjectiveWithKeyResults.getKeyResults(), HttpStatus.OK));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/objectives/1/keyresult"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].keyResultId", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].description", is("My parent Key Result is 1")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].completed", is(false)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].keyResultId", is(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].description", is("My parent Key Result is 1")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].completed", is(true)));

    }
}
```

My question is this:
Having mocked the objective controller using Mockito to validate that my objects are being formed properly, I now want to do the same thing but instead of mocking, I want to actually test the controller.

What do you think is the most naive way of getting this to work (I can refactor later). The resources I've search through either use different versions of Junit or rely on mockito rather than the actual controller.

Nothing fits quite right - since the controller is mocked, I'm not actually covering any code, and so the tests are worthless right? The only thing I'm looking at is that the objects are formed properly, where I now need to check that the controller is functioning as it should, AND are returning well formed objects.

Has anyone done anything simillar? What approaches do you use to manage the testing of field injected controllers?

Any advice on this would be hugely appreciated. I'd love to learn how people working on production grade applications are handling the testing of Spring Boot Apps with Controllers, Repos, etc.

Thanks so much!

Comment: do you want to test just one controller or the whole app? Have you tried just add the controller to the classpath like `@WebMvcTest({
        Controller1.class, Controlelr2.class
})`

Comment: please if the answer I posted solves your problem, click on "accept" (grey tick)

Comment: Hi @dehasi - In this one test class, I just want to test the one controller :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use @SpyBean. That way you can both use it as it is or mock some calls. https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy

Comment: Thanks for telling me about spies. They seem useful in some case, but aren't what I'm looking for here. I don't want to have Mockito wrap the controller, I just want to call the controller directly.

Comment: Behaviour of the controller will be as if Mockito is not there as long as you do not have set up a "when().thenReturn();" for a method. If you really want to test the mocked on one side and the "real" on other side you need to have it on two different test classes. One with the annotation and one without anything. Spring will take care of recreating the beans for the different tests.